# Passing Array to the component

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and need help in following..

I have following component that is accepting array list to render the components and need a seperate component to manipulate the array

Component that is rendering:

```
export function DashboardContent() {
    return (
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Col sm={12} md={12} lg={4}>
                <ProfileCard />
            </Grid.Col>
            <Grid.Col sm={12} md={12} lg={8}>
                <Flex direction="column" h="100%" justify="space-between" gap="md">
                    <WelcomeCard />
                    <StatsGroup data={mockData} />
                </Flex>
            </Grid.Col>
            <Grid.Col sm={12} md={12} lg={8}>
                <BalanceCard />
            </Grid.Col>
            <Grid.Col sm={12} md={12} lg={4}>
                <OverviewCard />
            </Grid.Col>
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

mockData is where I need to pass the array using API calls
Currently passing following mock data:

```
export const mockData = [
    {
        title: 'ABC',
        value: '$7,999',
        diff: 50,
    },
    {
        title: 'XXX',
        value: '$4,00',
        diff: -13,
    },
    {
        title: 'Null',
        value: '$ 0.745',
        diff: 1,
    },
];
```

Need help with a new component js that can be managed independently to make API calls and pass array in format described in mock.

have been trying below code with no luck and any help will be appreciated

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

interface CustomArray {
    title: string;
    value: string;
    diff: number;
}
const token =
    'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
});
const Usage = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

    const fetchUsers = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(
            'https://myrestservices.com/api/v2/organizations/AXZ/usage'
        );
        const usersData = response.data;

        const usersArray = usersData.map(user => ({
            title: user.title,
            value: user.value,
            diff: user.diff,
        }));

        setUsers(usersArray);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchUsers();
    }, []);

    return users;
};

export default Usage;
```

Comment: use array `map()` method and call you component by passing each value of array to component and recieve that data as props and show them

Comment: Could you please elaborate with code?

Comment: Answer given below in correct example. If have have any problem at any point I will explain.

Answer (score 1):

The very first thing needs to be done is change the implementation of Usage to react custom hook like

```
const useApiData = (apiUrl) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(apiUrl);
      const responseData = response.data;

      const dataArray = responseData.map(item => ({
        title: item.title,
        value: item.value,
        diff: item.diff,
      }));

      setData(dataArray);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [apiUrl]);

  return data;
};

export default useApiData;
```

Then to render this data make changes inside your StatsGroup component like below.

```
const StatsGroup = ({ apiData }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {apiData.map(item => (
        <div key={item.title}>
          <p>Title: {item.title}</p>
          <p>Value: {item.value}</p>
          <p>Diff: {item.diff}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default StatsGroup;
```

So to link between the custom hook and StatGroup component call the custom hook first and after getting result pass the data to StatGroup in a prop like below.

```
const DashboardContent = () => {
  // Use any API URL you want to fetch data from
  const apiUrl = 'https://myrestservices.com/api/v2/organizations/AXZ/usage';
  
  const apiData = useApiData(apiUrl);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Stats Group</h1>
      <StatsGroup apiData={apiData} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default DashboardContent;
```